# Is "don't" a particle of its own?

Tags: negation, contractions, subject-verb-inversion, auxiliary-verbs, descriptive-grammar

I noticed an oddity in the sentence *Why don't you just do it?*: Although I always thought of *don't* simply as of a short form of *do not* it seems to me as if this is not the case in this sentence. Instead, *don't* appears as a particle of its own, i.e. it cannot be deconstructed any more. The sentence **Why do not you just do it?* sounds ungrammatical to me, but *Why don't you just do it?* seems fine. (I am not a native speaker.)

I have three questions:

1. Is "don't" a particle of its own?
2. Is there a name for this grammatical phenomenon?
3. Are there other cases besides negated questions where *don't* cannot be deconstructed?

Comment: Don't let's worry about this too much.

Comment: Not sure if any of these are precise dupes, but see [Why is "Why don't you like ___?" okay, but "Why do not you like?" ___?" isn't?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60952/why-is-why-dont-you-like-okay-but-why-do-not-you-like-isnt), [Expanding a contraction, where the expansion is not as it would seem](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181147/expanding-a-contraction-where-the-expansion-is-not-as-it-would-seem?rq=1), and [Is "Don't you know? " the same as "Do not you know?"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14287/is-dont-you-know-the-same-as-do-not-you-know).

Comment: I *think* (don't *know*) that ***don't*** has been ***gramaticalized.*** Full Oxford English Dictionary: *To express by means of the grammatical structure; to adopt as a grammatical requirement. Usually in passive.* Again, I *think* this can be contrasted with ***lexicalize***: (1) *To accept into the lexicon, or vocabulary, of a language,* (2) *To express (a difference that is already expressed in the grammatical structure, or could be) by means of a different lexical item.*

Comment: You might ask a followup here: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/19006/analyzing-negation-with-a-syntactic-tree

Comment: Why don't you just do it?=Why do you not just do it. "don't you" is negative interrogative.

Comment: Arguably, "don't" / "doesn't" is a [negative auxiliary verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_verb). That's not the way it's _usually_ analyzed in English, but it works pretty much exactly like the negative verbs in Uralic languages like Finnish, Estonian and Sami.

Comment: Just what do you mean by a “particle”? Do you mean like the *to* in English infinitives, or *zu* in German ones? Or do you mean a [clitic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic) or another sort of [bound morpheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morpheme#Classification_of_bound_morphemes)? Are you perhaps thinking of how some German verbs have “separable particles” (*trennbare Vorsilben*) whose leading bit (its “prefix”, as *aus‑* in *ausbleiben*, *durch‑* in *durchfahren*, and *her‑* in *hertragen*) ᴄᴀɴ and under specific circumstances ᴍᴜꜱᴛ detach to independently move elsewhither syntactically?

Comment: Once something is analyzed as a word, it takes on a life of its own, separate from the components it was formed from. It's the same reason why the «"PIN number" is wrong» argument is wrong.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Indeed! From PIE both Latin and OE inherited a free negative lexeme or particle *ne* which could also be used proclitically to derive negated verbs but of which few vestiges now remain in today’s English or Romance.  Ancient examples include: L. *nolo/nescio* meaning don’t want/know, < *ne‑* + positives *volo/scio* for want/know; OE+ME *nit* < *ne wit* meaning to not know, to know not; or as in *will he or nill he* where *nill* < *ne‑* + *will*.

Comment: @tchrist I realize I probably used the term _particle_ in a wrong way. What I want to get across with the term is that it is something "atomic", i.e. it cannot be deconstructed into smaller parts. Reading _don't_ as a contraction of _do not_ would render it as a complex, composed, non-atomic entity. I think you are right that in assuming that my use of the term draws inspiration from the separable particles in German.

Comment: Yours was not a “wrong way” *sensu stricto* so much as one I worried readers might lack the background or context to understand. See the supercited [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic#Comparison_with_affixes) and especially [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic#English) where they write: “The negative marker *‑n’t* as in *couldn’t* etc. is typically considered a clitic that developed from the lexical item *not*. Linguists Arnold Zwicky and Geoffrey Pullum argue, however, that the form has the properties of an affix rather than a syntactically independent clitic.”

Comment: _Why do not you just do it?_ is not idiomatic. However, _Why do you not just do it?_ might be uncommon, but to this native speaker, it is 100% idiomatic. It allows emphasis that using _don't_ doesn't. _Why **do** you not just do it?_ _Why do you **not** just do it?_

Comment: Is this simply about someone having persuaded you that 'don't' isn't just as easily used as a contraction of '… do not…' as of '…do you not…'?

Either way, what made you think 'don't' could have any meaning 'of its own', as a particle or anything else? Are you suggesting 'don't' could be something other than a contraction

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Well, I don't think _don't_ is a contraction in the example sentence, as it cannot be re-expanded any more. I don't understand the rest of your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Questions like *Why **do you** play chess?* display subject auxiliary inversion; the auxiliary verb *do* appears before the subject *you*.

In a normal declarative clause, the adverb *not* occurs after the first auxiliary, before the next verb in the chain of verbs (or before any modifiers of that following verb phrase):

1. You do **not** [play chess].
2. You do **not** [just play chess].

If we have subject auxiliary inversion, the adverb *not* stays in this same position:

3. Do you **not** [play chess]?

However, if—and only if—the adverb *not* is contracted with the auxiliary, in this case the verb *do*, it gets pulled along with it to the pre-subject position:

4. Do**n't** you [play chess]?

This is exactly what is happening is the Original Poster's example:

5. Why do you **not** [just do it]?
6. Why do**n't** you [just do it].
7. *Why do **not** you [just do it]? (ungrammatical)

Above we see that (7) is ungrammatical because the negative adverb *not* is not in its normal position before the following verb phrase. It cannot move from this position because it is not contracted with the auxiliary verb.

Some writers, for example *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002), argue that *don't* and other negative 'contractions' are not actually contractions at all, but negative inflections of the auxiliary verb. They cite evidence such as the fact that *won't* is nothing like an amalgam of the words *will* and *not*, as well as the phenomenon noticed by the Original Poster in their question. Notice that although with *do* and *don't* it looks from the spelling as if we have just tacked ***n't*** onto the verb *do*, the vowel in *don't* is completely different from the vowel in *do*, and thus the situation is very similar to the one with *will* and *won't*.

**Other environments where *don't* cannot deconstruct:**

Unlike the situation with negative questions, where it could be argued that *don't* can deconstruct, but not *in situ*—the *not* must appear in a different position, not next to the auxiliary—there is one case where *don't* does not readily deconstruct at all. It is also a case where some people have argued that *don't* is actually a marker and not a verb. This is the case of negative imperatives with subjects. And this time, the phenomenon really is to do with the item *do*, and not to do with auxiliaries in general.

Imperatives often occur without a subject:

8. Dance!

If we want to negate the imperative we can use either the item *don't* or the two words *do not*:

9. Don't dance!
10. Do not dance!

So far, so good. Now, imperatives can also come with subjects. These are usually either the second person singular pronoun *you* or a word like *somebody, anybody, nobody* and so forth:

11. *You* dance!
12. Everybody dance!

**[** These are pronounced very differently from the case where we have a vocative expression like *Bertha/you/everybody*, where we would expect a separate prosodic unit (a separate tune) for the vocative:

13. Bertha, dance!
14. You, dance!
15. Everybody! Dance!**]**

Now, if we want to negate an imperative clause that has an expressed subject, we need to put the word *don't* **before** the subject:

16. Don't you dance!
17. Don't everyone talk at  once.

However, here, there doesn't seem to be any good way at all of decomposing the *don't* into two separate words in these cases, especially with a second person subject:

18. *Do not you dance! (ungrammatical)
19. *Do you not dance! (ungrammatical imperative - would be ok as question)

Comment: Ha! Try to repeat "wiln't" ten times and we'll see if it won't become anything like "won't"

Comment: @Stef Well, define “anything like”. To me, repeating _willn’t_ produces something like [wɪɫʷnt] or perhaps [wɪwnt] if the /l/ is debuccalised altogether. Is that ‘anything like’ _won’t_? Sure. Is it the same vowel as the /oʊ/ in _won’t_? No. Don’t forget that the vowel quality in _won’t_ comes more from the formerly common present form _woll_ than from _will_.

Comment: I don't know how to say "You dance!" and "Everbody dance!" *except* when "you" and "everybody" are separate prosodic units, so I'm not sure what you mean there.

Comment: "Sheltie, step forward. Shiba Inu, step forward. Wolfhound, step forward".  They're all being addressed  individually and told what to do.

Comment: @TimR Yes, and that's why they're vocatives and also why the negation of those imperatives has the *don't* afetr and not before the vocative phrase.

Comment: What about "Do not dance, you!", or "Do not dance, everybody!"?  That's how I would probably say it if I felt the need to include the subject in the imperative when using "do not".  (And that can also be contracted to *don't* and still sound correct.)

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Good question. Those words at the end there *everybody* or *you* are vocatives. They tell you who the sentence is addressed to. The best clue there is the preceding comma, which tells us that those words/phrases have their own intonational phrase. You can use those with an imperative with its own subject. For example "*You dance, you*" or "*Don't you dance, you!*"

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Zwicky and Pullum’s point about English’s ᴍᴀɴʏ auxiliaries negated via *‑n’t*, including both modal and non-modal ones alike (*won’t, don’t/didn’t, isn’t/aren’t/weren’t, hasn’t/hadn’t, can’t, shan’t/shouldn’t, oughtn’t, daren’t*, etc) is that these behave syntactically far more like integral/first-order lexemes derived by affixation than they do ones with a syntactically independent enclitic you’d be able to freely break up and move independently, including by interposing other syntactic elements between the deconstructed pieces—as you ᴄᴀɴ ᴅᴏ in *the Queen of England’s hat*.

Comment: I’m left pondering whether the negative imperative *Don’t you dare dance!* can ᴇᴠᴇʀ have a corresponding positive version and if so what that is—and if not, then why it cannot do so.

Comment: @tchrist I doubt it, but some writers believe that pseudo-conditional constructions like *(You do/)Do that again, (and) you're fired* contain an imperative form even though the speaker doesn't want the listener to 'do that again'.  I'm not sure about that though. There seems to be a clear contrast between *You dare dance and I'm leaving* which has no command-like force and  where *You dare xyz* is possible and ? *You dare dance **or** I'm leaving*, where the first conjunct needs to be a real imperative, but seems ungrammatical or at least infelicitous.  Compare: *Apologise, or I'm leaving*.

Comment: Are those examples at the end of this answer actually imperatives or are they some kind of subjunctive?

Comment: @CarstenS Which examples? (16) and (17)?

Comment: @tchrist Sorry forgot to explain why I doubt it, which is basically because *dare* there seems to be modal-like in that it's taking a bare infinitival construction as complement. And modal *dare*'s a negative polarity item. [However, a modal with *do*-support is squifffy. The data for *dare* is all over the place].

Comment: @Araucaria-Him, I was thinking foremost of (12) and then maybe (11). I of course realise that such a distinction is rather pointless in English, because those forms are jdentical to the infinitive anyway.

Comment: @CarstenS That's right. We can't really talk about infinitival, subjunctive and imperative forms of the verb (well, one can, but it's very difficult to justify), but we can talk about subjunctive constructions and imperative constructions and so forth. One of the main ways imperatives with subjects are traditionally differentiated from subjunctives is by negation. Subjunctives take *not*, whereas imperatives require *don't/do not*, in other words they require *do*-support. So that would seem to  confirm (11-12) as imperatives, if we take that line of thinking.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him, thank you for the explanation, that’s interesting.